# How do you temporarily "class_eval" for a test?

Tags: ruby, class-eval

Is it possible to temporarily apply certain methods to a class for tests? I want to be able to run specs depending on many ways to apply it. While I could make a bunch of fixtures with different settings, I find it easier to just `class_eval` the model in the tests. For example:

```
describe "some context"
  before do
    Page.class_eval do
      my_applying_method :some => :option
    end
  end

  it "should..."
end
```

Then in another context block:

```
describe "another context without the gem applied"
  before do
    Page.class_eval do
      # nothing here since I want to page to be as is
    end
  end

  it "should do something else..."
end
```

But the **problem** with the last context block is that it has a modified class (modified in the context block above). **Is it possible to reset a class after `class_eval`**? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't clarified how you are modifying the class.

The [remix](https://github.com/banister/remix) library allows you to temporarily include a module and properly uninclude it later.

In general, it's probably safest to just duplicate the class and test the duplicate:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Foo; end
#=> nil
irb(main):002:0> Foo.dup.class_eval{ @x = 42 }
#=> 42
irb(main):003:0> Foo.class_eval{ @x }
#=> nil
```

Comment: Ah I `include` other modules with `some_applying_method`. Like a typical plugin. Thanks this will help!

Answer (score 2):

I hope there is a better way to do that but you can use this(and it's with a warning at the `Foo = Foo_old` line):

```
module Bar
  def baz
  end
end

class Foo
end

puts Foo.method_defined? :baz #=> false
Foo_old = Foo.dup # create a copy of our class

Foo.class_eval do
  include Bar
end

puts Foo.method_defined? :baz #=> true
Foo = Foo_old
puts Foo.method_defined? :baz #=> false
```

Comment: This no longer works, as Foo is a constant (and is not able to be dynamically assigned).